# Moving first row of csv into header HTML

Tags: javascript, html, csv, parsing, html-table

I create a table with ajax, but can't seem to enclose the `<th>` elements inside the `<tr id="header">`. I've tried the `appendTo`, `prependTo`, but no luck.

The structure I want is: `<Table><Thead><tr><th>`, so that the data that would go in `th` would be children to `#header`, not siblings

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table id = "data_table"></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        if (i==0){
            var row = $('<thead class= "table_header"><tr id="header"></tr></thead>');

            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            $('#header').append($('<th>'+cellData+'</th>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
        } else{
            var row = $('<tr class="table_data"></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
            });
        table.append(row);
        }
    });
    return table;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "random/folder/with/csvs/csv1.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#container').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
    if (i==0){
        var head = $('<thead class= "table_header"></thead>');
        var row = $('<tr id="header"></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<th>'+cellData+'</th>'));
        });
        head.append(row);
        table.append(head);
    } else{
        var row = $('<tr class="table_data"></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        table.append(row);
    }
});
```