# Partially display csv file while continue to load it into background using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, csv, asynchronous

I have on the local server the following files:

**data.csv:**

> **(It is a very huge .csv file with over 350.000 rows.)**

```
Day,Hour,N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,N10,N11,N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20
1996-03-18,15:00,4,9,10,16,21,22,23,26,27,34,35,41,42,48,62,66,68,73,76,78
1996-03-19,15:00,6,12,15,19,28,33,35,39,44,48,49,59,62,63,64,67,69,71,75,77
1996-03-21,15:00,2,4,6,7,15,16,17,19,20,26,28,45,48,52,54,69,72,73,75,77
1996-03-22,15:00,3,8,15,17,19,25,30,33,34,35,36,38,44,49,60,61,64,67,68,75
1996-03-25,15:00,2,10,11,14,18,22,26,27,29,30,42,44,45,55,60,61,66,67,75,79
1996-03-26,15:00,4,10,12,19,20,22,30,31,32,37,44,45,55,57,60,61,64,69,70,72
1996-03-28,15:00,1,4,9,11,12,13,15,26,32,35,39,40,49,53,62,63,72,73,77,78
1996-03-29,15:00,3,9,13,14,24,27,29,32,35,41,44,47,49,50,61,64,66,69,72,73
1996-04-01,15:00,2,4,6,9,12,14,20,21,25,35,39,43,44,45,48,50,52,61,69,72
```

...

**main.js:**

> **(It is loading the data.csv and display it into the html table from**
> **index.html.)**

```
// (A) GET HTML TABLE
//let table = document.getElementById("data_table");

// (B) AJAX FETCH CSV FILE
fetch("data.csv")
    .then((res) => { return res.text(); })
    .then((csv) => {
        // (B1) REMOVE OLD TABLE ROWS
        table.innerHTML = "";

        // (B2) GENERATE TABLE
        csv = csv.split("\r\n");
        for (let row of csv) {
            let tr = table.insertRow();
            for (let col of row.split(",")) {
                let td = tr.insertCell();
                td.innerHTML = col;
            }
        }
    });
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <title>CSV To HTML Table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- GENERATE HTML TABLE HERE -->
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search here..."
        title="Type in a a number to search for.">
    <table id="data_table"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

All the code above is working very well but there is something I need you to help me with, please:

1. Read first row of the data.csv and load it into table header because
   I want to apply some other css styles to it.
2. Read only the next 100 rows just after the header and display them
   into the table body in order to apply styles to them too.
3. I want to display only first 100 rows because data.csv file is huge
   and it takes a lot of time to load and display it. But I want to
   load/read it into background and while it is not fully read the
   input type with the id "myInput" to be invisible or disabled in
   order to be able to search on the full table only when it is fully
   loaded.

I tried also to **partially** solve the problem applying the (modified) solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935311/moving-first-row-of-csv-into-header-html) but it is not working at all. (Also, how to continue to load data in background after displaying first 100 rows?)

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var table = $('<table id = "data_table"></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        if (i==0){
            var head = $('<thead class= "table_header"></thead>');
            var row = $('<tr id="header"></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<th>'+cellData+'</th>'));
            });
            head.append(row);
            table.append(head);
        } else{
            var row = $('<tr class="table_data"></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
            });
            table.append(row);
        }
    });
    return table;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#container').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});
```

It seems many people is looking for what I'm asking here but there isn't any clear solution so I think this is gonna help many people.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need pagination https://www.google.com/search?q=csv+paging++site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: As I can understand using pagination is as follow: 1. Read csv file and load it into array. Right? 2. Create and display pages with tables from that array. The problem arises exactly from the step one because the pages index.html doesn't display anything until the csv file is not fully read and being a huge file it stops. Also, while online it will take forever to load and visitors will go away.

Comment: No. Pagination is on the server. You load the first 100 or thousand rows when the page loads and ajax the next x number of rows when the user scrolls. Also called lazy loading